# Port 22: Connection Refused when you attempt to ssh in

Tags: ssh, server, port, remote-access, centos7

On Centos 7 I am faced with the error below:

```
ssh -vvv ##.###.###.###
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ##.###.###.### [##.###.###.###] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ##.###.###.### port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ##.###.###.### port 22: Connection refused
pool-100-1-1-25:~ studiolaptop1$ ssh -vvv ##.###.###.###
```

Bizarrely, I have been getting this issue for awhile now when I try to ssh into my server. I have checked iptables looks all fine. Checked the ssh.config file, that is also looking fine, but clearly something is wrong. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to login as root? On some Linux distributions, ssh root login has been disabled in newer versions (e.g. Arch Linux). You'd have to reenable it in sshd_config. (PermitRootLogin= true)

Comment: Nope I have another user that I am using to ssh. Was working fine but all of a sudden ain't.

Comment: Then your best bet is to log the communication attempt via tcpdump and exame it with Wireshark. Perhaps there's another host with that IP in your network (with port 22 closed).

Comment: I shall attempt that, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from firewallD to iptables had caused this issue. Thus, needed to  add relevant rules to the iptable to allow outbound and inbound connection on port 22.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is refused, it means the sshd daemon/server is not running.  Can you login to the server locally or via a console?

Try running the following as root on the target server:

```
lsof -i :22
```

or on the source server, see if you can connect to the ssh port:

```
telnet targethost 22
```

You should get something like the following:

```
# telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
```

Comment: lsof will show if anything is listening on port 22, the default port for ssh.  Of course you can also just look and see what the status is of the sshd daemon, but if you can see that it is running on the target server, then that's one thing to rule out.

Comment: Sorry of course it is. I have checked and weirdly port 22 is listening fine.

Comment: Do you have a rule in your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file that only allows certain hosts?  I always recommend starting another server instance in debug mode and then connecting to that to see what happens.  The debug output on the server side is often more useful than the verbose output of the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490950/ssh-login-between-servers-still-asking-for-password-why/33495829#33495829

Answer (score 0):

I loaded promox and did not update host had a static ip and could connect once I trying windows 10 to rpi4 window you goto apps add options feature add both `openssh` goto rp1 copy `ssh/ssh_config` paste `.ssh/config`  put it folder says that missing when you do `ssh -vvv root@raspberry pi` you have to do `ssh-keygen` command in windows and rp14 you check in termial of rpi `ssh root@rasperry ls -l /usr/local` then go in to known hosts in window ssh folder type in `127.0.0.1 raspberrypi` in known hosts file and have apache2 running raspberrypi then you have to copy password file over to windows you have to do to `# #` two line in ssh_config file and make a `/dev/tty` empty file on windows

Comment: I edited this to the best of my ability, but it isn't very clear what you intend to be command and what you intend to be instructions.  Can you clarify?